# I keep running into the same problems every time I try to make a new program

Tags: java, oop

My current program is a simple game..  I am trying to make it to help figure out how to properly use OOP.  But every time I get a little bit into a new program I run into the same problem:

I make an instance to use in my game.  This instance could be anything - the main hero, a monster, whatever.  Everything is going good, the instance is exactly what I want it to be.  Maybe I manipulate it a little bit.

I then try to use a different class, I guess I create an instance of a different class, in an attempt to further manipulate the original instance.  Maybe I originally created my hero and changed his stats, and now at this point I am trying to have my hero say something based on the stats that were chosen.

This point is always where I hit a roadblock.  I can't seem to do what I want to do here - I can't use that original instance I made because It was just an instance and I don't know how to manipulate it(or even if I am supposed to) from within a new class.

So.. it's a fundamental design problem/lack of understanding of OOP.
But I feel like I have a decent grasp on how to actually program stuff.. I keep reading and reading and getting advice but I can't seem to get past this barrier.

I know people on this site don't seem to like posts like this but maybe someone here can Identify with what it is I am not grasping.

Here is an example of what I am talking about, the game I am trying to make right now.

```
package pkgnew.stupid.game;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author whyguy2
 */
public class Hero {
public static int heroattack = 1;
public static int herospeed = 1;
public static int heroarmorpen = 1;
public static int heroarmor = 1;
public static int herohealth = 5;
public static String inputstat;
public static int herothepoints = 0;

Hero(int points){
    spendpoint(points);
}





    public void attack(){

    }

    public void die(){
       System.exit(0);
    }

    public void winbattle(){
        System.out.println("You win the battle and have one new point to spend!");
        spendpoint(1);
        new NewEncounter();
    }

    public void levelup(){
        System.out.println("You have leveled up and receive 5 new points to spend");
        spendpoint(5);
        new NewEncounter();
    }

    public void spendpoint(int points){
        for(int x=0; x<points; x++){
    System.out.println("Available Points: " + points);
    System.out.println("Available Attributes:");
    System.out.println("attack: " + heroattack); 
    System.out.println("speed: " + herospeed);
    System.out.println("armorpen: " + heroarmorpen);
    System.out.println("armor: " + heroarmor);
    System.out.println("health: " + herohealth);
    System.out.println(points);
    System.out.println(x);
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );
    inputstat = keyboard.next( );
    if(inputstat.equals("attack")){
    heroattack = heroattack + 1;    
    }
    else if(inputstat.equals("speed")){
    herospeed = herospeed + 1;    
    }
    else if(inputstat.equals("armorpen")){
    heroarmorpen = heroarmorpen + 1;    
    }
    else if(inputstat.equals("armor")){
    heroarmor = heroarmor + 1;    
    }
    else if(inputstat.equals("health")){
    herohealth = herohealth + 5;    
    } 
    else{
    System.out.println("Please pick one of the stats");
    x = x-1;
    }
        }

    }

}





public class StartGame {

    StartGame(){                                                            //runs through output for a new game
   System.out.println("Welcome to the game");
   System.out.println("Pick your hero's starting stats");
   Hero thishero = new Hero(10);                                                             //spends your points

   System.out.println("Let's Begin!/n/n");
   new NewEncounter();                                                              //goes into the encounter loops
    }   

}
```

at this point I I try to program an encounter in the NewEncounter class, but that isn't possible because I can't use that instance of my hero that I created.  and I am pretty sure that my design is bad in the first place, I think I have read that you should be trying to use static variables as little as possible in the first place.  I am still reading trying to grasp this but I have read a lot and I feel like nothing is helping me.  I actually think a more "hands on" large scale project/tutorial might help me, but I don't know one.  Anyways thanks for any help and sorry for the long/blog-like post.

Comment: Not sure if it's related but why are your variables static? You add values to it throughout the game, they shouldn't be static then

Comment: I would first change `NewEnconter` to just `Encounter` for better naming purposes.  Then you need to think of a design of how the `Encounter` class and the `Hero` class talk to eachother.   This could be done by passing in the hero class to encounter on the constructor `new Encounter(thishero)` or perhaps the `Hero` class holding on to the reference of the current encounter with a class variable.

Comment: "...at this point I I try to program an encounter in the NewEncounter class, but that isn't possible because..."  Are you getting a run-time error message?  A compile-time error message?  What is the message?  On which line of the program does the error occur?

Comment: You create an instance of Hero in StartGame() and then you do nothing with it. You should probably hold on to your reference to thishero somewhere.

Comment: bhspencer how do I "hold onto it" ?

Comment: oh i see the person below is showing how.  I will look over his code, thank you for the answers everyone.  and james, what happens is that I can't use any objects I had previously created because if I try to it tells me that it can't find them.  Can't find symbol method whatever().

Comment: @TravisBlack do you know about references?

Comment: a reference is the name that you give a new instance, right?  like Hero myhero = new Hero(), the reference would be myhero?  I think my issue is that I am never moving my references into new objects through their parameters.  not sure I am using the terminology correctly there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard way to use an instance of one class within another is to either store a reference to it or to pass it into the method that stores or uses it.

For example:

```
class Encounter {
    private final Hero mainHero;
    private final List<Hero> participants;

    public Encounter(Hero mainHero) {
        this.mainHero = mainHero;
        participants = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addParticipant(Hero hero) {
        participants.add(hero);
    }
}
```

Allows:

```
Encounter encounter = new Encounter(hero);
```

or:

```
encounter.addParticipant(hero);
```

These can then be used within the class. For example:

```
class Encounter {
    public void moveAllParticipants() {
        participants.forEach(Hero::move);
    }
}
```

I notice you have used a lot of public static class variables. This is unusual and there are few good reasons to use them. One is to define constants. If that's your intent then I suggest you use the following standard form:

```
private static final int HERO_ATTACK = 1;
```

If you intend for these to be instance variables (i.e. different for each hero) then they should not be static nor public.

This is the sort of area that is well covered in the various Java tutorials. I suggest working through one of them and coming back here if you have further issues.

Comment: Very thorough explanation

Comment: just wanted to let you know this is exactly what I needed